# Karate: local retry interval

Tags: karate

I'm configuring the global retry interval in karate-config.js:

```
function config(){
  karate.configure('retry', { count: 10, interval: 500});
}
```

I need to increase that interval in only one call:

```
Given path 'endpoint'
And configure retry = { count: 20, interval: 2000} #Change interval
And retry until response == ...something...
And configure retry = { count: 10, interval: 500} #Reestablish interval
When method get
```

Is there any shorter way to change the retry interval locally?

Thanks

Comment: you know what, you should just write your own framework and leave us maintainers in peace :P

Comment: No, I like karate framework. I just want to do things in the cleanest way.

Comment: no worries. I think you are really pushing karate to the limits, which is great. would be great to have a call with you one of these days, to get some user feedback.

Comment: Sure!! But don't get angry :-P

Comment: I promise ! please use the contact form at https://karatelabs.io and I'll get in touch

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. You are welcome to contribute code.